# Block asp.net mvc Html creation in using scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use an HTML helper that returns an IDisposable to create a specific DIV structure that I need very often in my application. The constructor of this class creates the open divs while the Dispose method created to closing Divs. Now I need to secure my application and I would like this structure not to be created in some condition but I also need that every kind of HTML that this produced between using and the end if its scope is also not rendered.

First thing I did was to replace the TextWriter found int he ViewContext with dummy :

```
_helper.ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
```

Its working for each piece of code that directly uses the ViewContext Writer to render HTML but not for the others (raw HTML and other helper)

So the question is : How can we prevent a Asp.net view to render HTML within the scope of a using block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no example code for you, and this idea is pretty hackish but may work if you have a zillion of these things you need to secure and don't have time to add condition logic.

What if you used the app's Response.Filter to strip out html? Then in your constructor and dispose methods, if the user isn't authorized to see the content, output some easy to find elements that you could either regex replace or use Html Agility Pack to parse/modify the DOM before the stream is sent to the browser.

Comment: Totally agree with you but I do have like a thousand place were it will be used , will try the hackish filter approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that currently there's no way of preventing the contents of a `using` block to be rendered. That was not the original intent of this block anyway. If you want to prevent something from being rendered you might consider using an `if` statement instead.